# Is there any way to only backup metadata of artifactory repositories and NOT the content

Tags: artifactory

I a looking for a way to only backup the metadata for any particular repo or file and not the actual content itself, I have the content already present so just wanted to know if I can backup the metadata of the artifacts? Any API or something

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no way to backup/export only one specific repository metadata. However, we can do full system export of Artifactory with exclude content and then import specific repository metadata only.